# Expected Win (or Loss) of Base (Spin) Game and Bonus (Guess the Colour) Game

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the right way of calculating an expected win (or loss) for a slot base game spin with a bonus game (guess the colour).

Let's say a player makes a `$1` bet and gets a combination that pays `$10` (еру base game). The player can either take their winnings (`$10`) or play the bonus game. In the bonus game the player has to guess the colour (red or black). If the player guesses it right, the winnings will be doubled (`2 × $10 = $20`). Otherwise, they lose the winnings (`$0`) and the bonus game stops. Again, the player can either take their winnings (`$20`) or play the next round of the bonus game. There are maximum of 5 bonus game rounds allowed.

Thus, there are the following possible outcomes:

- \$10 (the player decides not to play the bonus game. Just takes the prize they win in the base game);
- \$20, \$40, \$80, \$160, or \$320 (the player plays 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rounds of the bonus game and takes that prize);
- \$0 (the player plays 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rounds of the bonus game and loses).

Here is what I have tried so far:

For the win/loss table, I think the initial bet of `$1` should be used. Or, maybe, the potential prize from the previous round/game should be listed in the `Loss` column?

| Game | Round | Win, \$ | Loss, \$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Base | - | 10 | 0 |
| Bonus | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| Bonus | 2 | 40 | 1 |
| Bonus | 3 | 80 | 1 |
| Bonus | 4 | 160 | 1 |
| Bonus | 5 | 320 | 1 |

Probability of loss is $ p_{loss} = 1 - p_{win} $. But I'm not sure what probabilities of win should be used:

- `0.5` for all cases or
- `0.5` for the base game (probability the player will decide to play the bonus game) and $ 0.5^{round} $ for the bonus games (probability of getting all played rounds won) or
- something else, since not all combinations are possible (e.g., for 3 rounds, combination `win, loss, win` is impossible, since the bonus game ends after the loss). This looks like `0.5` should be used for all cases.

| Game | Round | p<sub>win</sub> | p<sub>loss</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Base | - | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Bonus | 1 | 0.5<sup>1</sup> = 0.5 | 1 – 0.5<sup>1</sup> = 0.5 |
| Bonus | 2 | 0.5<sup>2</sup> = 0.25 | 1 – 0.5<sup>2</sup> = 0.75 |
| Bonus | 3 | 0.5<sup>3</sup> = 0.125 | 1 – 0.5<sup>3</sup> = 0.875 |
| Bonus | 4 | 0.5<sup>4</sup> = 0.0625 | 1 – 0.5<sup>4</sup> = 0.9375 |
| Bonus | 5 | 0.5<sup>5</sup> = 0.03125 | 1 – 0.5<sup>5</sup> = 0.96875 |

Then, I think, the average of the expected values for the base and bonus games should be calculated as follows<sup>NOTE</sup>:

$$ E[game] = \frac{E[spin]+\sum_{i=1}^5 E[round_i]}{n_{spins}+n_{rounds}} = \frac{(p_{win}\times win-p_{loss}\times loss)_{spin}+\sum_{i=1}^5 (p_{win}\times win-p_{loss}\times loss)_{i}}{1+5} $$

So, the question is: what's the correct way to calculate the expected win for this case?

---

<sup>**NOTE**</sup> I'm not 100% sure that the formula is written correctly in terms of notation, since I'm not very familiar with the probability and statistics.

Comment: You'd realistically lose money, as a 1 dollar entry fee with a 50% of winning 10 dollars, means that everyone who only plays (only) the first round would make on average 4 dollars. And a lot of people would figure that out, (you should probably raise the entry fee)

Comment: Sejr, thank you for your comment, but I want to figure out how to calculate that.

Comment: I think I understand the quistion better now, so is it this? ( where B_win is the winning chance on base round, which seems to be different than the other bonus rounds. And P_stop is the chance of the player stopping every round ) (The player on average earns around 3.42):

$\frac{1}{1-P_{stop}^{1+R_{rounds}}}\left(\left(P_{stop}\right)\left(\left(B_{win}\right)\left(E_{earning}\right)-F_{fee}\right)+\left(B_{win}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{R_{rounds}}\left(P_{stop}^{1+n}\left(\left(P_{win}\right)^{\left(\frac{n^{2}+n}{2}\right)}\cdot\left(2\right)^{n}\cdot E_{earning}-F_{fee}\right)\right)\right)$

Comment: -So you want an entry fee on 5.53 or higher, if you want to earn money.

Comment: Sejr, correct me, if I'm wrong. The bonus game can be triggered only if the base game gives a win. Thus, $ B_{win} = 1 $. But there is a chance that the player will not play the bonus game (I believe it is `0.5`). I don't know what entry fee you mean. And I don't need to calculate it. I just need to calculate the expected win or loss with the given bet and prizes.

Comment: The $B_{win}$ is the chance of the player winning the first game, the base game, which is 50%? And I have already indcluded the chance of the player stopping, which is $P_{stop}$? Plus, it costs 1 to play the game? $P_{loss}$

Comment: If you set the base winning to 1, meaning that the player earns the 10 dollars no matter what, then they you'll lose 4.5 dollars every game.

Comment: I'm trying to analyse a single winning combination (not all possible game combinations). Thus, there are no chances to lose that base game combination. The bet can be any (\$1, \$2, \$3, …, \$100, and so on), but I'm analysing a \$1 bet.

Comment: Ohhhh... I think I get it, so are you trying to figure out the gain or loss from the bonus game? Like analysis if it should be included in this specific case? If so, you go from loosing 9 dollars (10 gain and a bet of 1) to an average expected loss of 4.5 dollars, and in this case you've gained 4.5 dollars from having the bonus game?

Comment: Serj, I'm trying to analyse the gain or loss from the bonus game and the basic game win (so, I want to take into account the scenario that the player won't play the bonus game and will just withdraw what they've won in the basic game). I've added the possible outcomes of the win to the question. Looks like I have to find an average of all those variants: $ \frac{10+20+40+80+160+320+0+0+0+0+0}{11} \approx \$57.28 $. But I'm not sure that this is right approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that the equation below is what you are lookin for, I would recommend playing around with it in Desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sq5gkraui7)

$\text{Average Earning after 1 game}=-\frac{1}{1-P_{stop}^{1+R_{rounds}}}\left(\left(P_{stop}\right)\left(\left(B_{win}\right)\left(E_{earning}\right)-F_{fee}\right)+\\  \left(B_{win}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{R_{rounds}}\left(P_{stop}^{1+n}\left(\left(P_{win}\right)^{\left(\frac{n^{2}+n}{2}\right)}\cdot\left(2\right)^{n}\cdot E_{earning}-F_{fee}\right)\right)\right)$

(Where $B_{win}$ is the winning chance on base round, which seems to be different than the other bonus rounds. And $P_{stop}$ is the chance of the player stopping every round, the rest should be self explanatory )

The player on average earns around 3.42, and if you want to make money, the entry fee has to be around 5.53 or higher.